# What is this style of art called?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I was wondering what this style of art is called?

Reminds me of Mad magazine from the 1960s and 70's!

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Not all styles of art have a specific name. Perhaps you could describe it as a caricature, or perhaps just a slightly wonky painting.  Although [caricatures](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=caricature&form=HDRSC2&first=1&tsc=ImageBasicHover) usually have more stylized and exaggerated distortion, so this doesn't quite fit that genre. The background looks like spray paint art.

Comment: @BillyKerr Ahh I see what you mean. I've been meaning to get into vector art, and thought this was a version of that.

Comment: This is most certainly *not* vector art (and vector isn't a "style" - it's a method). There are some indications that it could be digitally painted as raster graphics (pixels). But it could also, like the old Mad Magazine illustrations, simply be drawn/painted by hand with a combination of materials like pencil, markers, airbrush, acrylic paint. A bit hard to tell in this resolution.